# Is there any Paypal REST API to verify a stored credit card using CVV

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm in the middle of integrating the Paypal payments with in my application. So when making the payment with the stored credit card is there any way to verify it using cvv by calling Paypal REST API before proceeding to payment?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify. You have a Vaulted credit card with its CVV. Customer is wanting to make a payment and you want to check to make sure the card is valid before running the payment? Wouldn't running the payment provide you the information you need? If the CVV is invalid or other issue, it would respond with that info?

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay to respond to your query, actually I was contacting with paypal customer support, but I didn't got anything positively from them till now. While making payment using a stored credit card using REST API the cvv is not required, its already saved with the card, and only the saved id of the card is required to use a stored credit card. So in this scenario how can I verify that the particular user is authorized to use the stored card, and is there any REST API to do the verification of the card either with cvv or any transaction password as an extra level of security.

Comment: I tried as you said, I stored the cvv when saving a card to vault but I'm not getting the cvv in response when doing look up. In the REST API documentation also there is no cvv in the response. The paypal actually hiding there informations due to security reasons. Thats why I'm stuck with this. Given below the sample response

Comment: {
  "id": "CARD-717XXXXXXXX",
  "number": "xxxxxxxxxxxx3404",
  "type": "visa",
  "expire_month": 4,
  "expire_year": 2018,
  "first_name": "John Doe",
  "external_customer_id": "1960928042",
  "state": "ok",
  "valid_until": "2018-11-15T00:00:00Z",
  "links": [
    {
      "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/...",
      "rel": "self",
      "method": "GET"
    },
    {
      "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/...",
      "rel": "delete",
      "method": "DELETE"
    },
    {
      "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/...",
      "rel": "patch",
      "method": "PATCH"
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
// 1. Autoload the SDK Package. This will include all the files and classes to your autoloader
require __DIR__  . '/PayPal-PHP-SDK/autoload.php';
// 2. Provide your Secret Key. Replace the given one with your app clientId, and Secret
// https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/myapps
$apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
    new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
        'AYSq3RDGsmBLJE-otTkBtM-jBRd1TCQwFf9RGfwddNXWz0uFU9ztymylOhRS',     // ClientID
        'EGnHDxD_qRPdaLdZz8iCr8N7_MzF-YHPTkjs6NKYQvQSBngp4PTTVWkPZRbL'      // ClientSecret


    )
);
// 3. Lets try to save a credit card to Vault using Vault API mentioned here
// https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#store-a-credit-card
$creditCard = new \PayPal\Api\CreditCard();
$creditCard->setType("visa")
    ->setNumber("4417119669820331")
    ->setExpireMonth("11")
    ->setExpireYear("2019")
    ->setCvv2("012")
    ->setFirstName("Joe")
    ->setLastName("Shopper");
// 4. Make a Create Call and Print the Card
try {
    $creditCard->create($apiContext);
   echo $creditCard;
    $mycard=json_decode($creditCard, true);

//echo json_encode($mycard["id"]);
$response["success"] = "1";
        $response["message"] = "update success";
$response["cardid"] = $mycard["id"] ;
echo '{"worldpopulation":'.json_encode($response).'}';
}
catch (\PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
    // This will print the detailed information on the exception. 
    //REALLY HELPFUL FOR DEBUGGING
$response["success"] = "0";
        $response["message"] = "not update success";

echo '{"worldpopulation":'.json_encode($response).'}';
    //echo $ex->getData();
}

?>
```

Comment: It would be better to provide some description with this code, if possible. Also, is it your own code? If not, it's important that you specify where it comes from, with a link to the original source, if at all possible.

Comment: A very quick Google showed that it is, indeed, not your own code, the original source is [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/File-based-Configurations)